# Preciso por um botão ao lado de um input do tipo select, como fazer?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3, html-select

Preciso por um botão ao lado de um input do tipo select. 
Meu código:

```
                       <div class="form-group col-md-2">    
                          <label for="inpIdPortador">ID Portador:</label>      
                            <select class="form-control" id="inpIdPortador">
                                <option value="1">Port 1</option>
                                <option value="1">Port 2</option>
                            </select>   
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize os recursos do próprio bootstrap.

Adicione uma class "row" antes de chamar o form-group e ative as classes 'col-md-*'

```
<form>
....
   <div class="row">    
       <fieldset class="form-group col-md-8">
           <label for="inpIdPortador">ID Portador:</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="inpIdPortador">
               <option value="1">Port 1</option>
               <option value="2">Port 2</option>
           </select>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="form-group col-md-4">
           <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block'></button>
       </fieldset>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumindo que o seu botão esteja fora da `div`, deve-se levar em consideração que o elemento `div` possui o `display: block`, isso faz com que tenha uma linha apenas para ela, então deve mudar para `display: inline-block` ou `display: inline`, assim será possível colocar o botão ao lado do seu `select`

```css
.form-group{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">    
 <label for="inpIdPortador">ID Portador:</label>      
 <select class="form-control" id="inpIdPortador">
  <option value="1">Port 1</option>
  <option value="1">Port 2</option>
 </select>   
</div>
<button>Botão</button>
```